# ExchangeService.FindFolders not returning any folders

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a function which loops through a number of defined folders in a mailbox. Each of the folders contains another folder called "Complete". The below code finds this "Complete" folder and gets its `FolderId`.

When run, the code works fine then after a while `FindFoldersResults findFolderProcessed = service.FindFolders(folder.Id, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Complete"), view);`  returns no folders. Stepping through the code, everything seems like it should work, but `findFolderProcessed.Folders` is empty.

Why would it work for a number of folders then stop?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxx@xxx.com");
service.Url = new Uri("https://xxx/ews/exchange.asmx");

FolderView view = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

SearchFilter[] parameters = new SearchFilter[3];
parameters[0] = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "x1");
parameters[1] = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "x2");
parameters[2] = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "x3");

SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection filterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, parameters);

FindFoldersResults findFolder = service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("xxx@xxx.com")), filterCollection, view);

foreach (Folder folder in findFolder.Folders)
{
    //FindFoldersResults tempResults = service.FindFolders(folder.Id, view);
    FindFoldersResults findFolderProcessed = service.FindFolders(folder.Id, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Complete"), view);
    FolderId ProcessedFolderID = findFolderProcessed.Folders[0].Id;

    //Other Processing
}
```

EDIT: Example Folder structure

```
x1
 -> Complete
x2
 -> Complete
x3
 -> Complete
...
xn
 -> Complete
```

There are around 50 folders, structured the exact same way.

Comment: you appear to have a major `disposing` of objects issue going on here when and where do you ever dispose of the `new'd` object instances that you have created..

Comment: Can you reproduce this? Does it happen for a certain folder or does it occur randomly? Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: MethodMan - Objects are disposed later on in the code, but this issue occurs before I want to dispose any of them.

khlr - Can I reproduce this? Yes, I reproduce it every time I run it. It does seem to be the same folders each time, I am doing more testing around this, but I don't know why.

I have put a description of the folder structure in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that `service.FindFolders` was returning duplicate folders and the loop was trying to process the folders twice. So it processed the folders correctly the first time around, but on the second go it was causing this issue.

I don't know why it would be returning duplicates, but to fix it I simply deduped `findFolder` by using the below code in place of `foreach (Folder folder in findFolder.Folders)`:

```
var folderCollection = findFolder.Folders.GroupBy(x => x.DisplayName).Select(g => g.First());

foreach (Folder folder in folderCollection)
```

If anyone knows why the folders would have been duplicated in the initial `service.FindFolders` call, feel free to comment below.