# EWS: WellKnownFolderName.Inbox returns 0 folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find the unique ID of a subfolder of the Inbox folder of a shared mail, named "Processed". When using WellKnownFolderName.Root and  a deep traversal, I find alot of different folders. But using the WellKnownFolderName.Inbox shows me 0 folders, as if there is 0 subfolders of the Inbox folder, which is not true.

```
ExchangeService Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
Service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");

Mailbox ProdSupportMailbox = new Mailbox("xxxx");
Service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxx");

FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = Service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

// Find specific folder
foreach(Folder f in findFolderResults)
{      
    if (f.DisplayName == "Processed")
        Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
        // etc
```

Comment: Have you seen this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697994/exchangeservice-findfolders-not-returning-any-folders

Comment: Yes, didn't help.

Comment: @JosephAwwal can you share a screenshot of your folder's hierarchy.?